# What does SR mean for track?

Tags: track-and-field

I know that there's a PR for personal record for track, I was looking as I SR and I have no clue what it means.

Comment: Could you provide an example where is it used? Is it possible that you mean *personal best* and *season's best*? These two are mentioned in the Wikipedia article: [Athletics abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athletics_abbreviations).

Comment: Related: https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/14182/35

Answer (score 3):

The usual notation is:

**PB:** Personal best
**SB**: Season's best

I assume that **PR** and **SR** are the same, but use 'Record' instead of 'Best'.

Note: I have also seen 'SR' used to mean 'Senior Record' (as opposed to 'JR' = 'Junior Record, so as Martin comments above, it does depend on context.

Generally though, I think this should be true.

Comment: In collegiate (e.g. NCAA) and high school results, 'SR' also shows up in results to denote that the athlete is in their fourth year of study, as in [Senior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senior_\(education\)).

Answer (score 0):

As Thevesh says, this really depends on context.

If you're seeing it in the published results or start lists of an event, it could me "Stadium Record", i.e. the best mark made at a particular facility. See [What does HF stand for in context of track and field abbreviations (WR, MR, etc)?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/14182/35) for examples of other such abbreviations; I didn't include "SR" in that list but perhaps I should have?

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, it's difficult to say. As noted in other answers, it could mean "Stadium Record" or "Season Record". (Although "Season Record" is odd phrasing to me - "Season Best" is much more common.) If it is a collegiate or other level of scholastic competition it may mean "School Record".